How do I remove a hat from my horse?
In Stardew Valley on the Nintendo Switch, I accidentally put a hat on my horse:

I mean, it's kinda cute, but how do I remove it on the Switch? I tried pressing Y, pressing A, and also tried grabbing it with the cursor but no luck.

Yet another title which looks interesting out of context on HNQ...

Simply hold another hat and put it on the horse. Doing so will remove the hat off its head first. You will need to click again to put on the new hat, so just click once to remove it.
Source, Reddit.

Confirmed. Hat has been removed from horse.

@JasonC glad to hear that :D
